# Can I ask computer-networking questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

I'm enrolled in a CCNA-networking course. I want to support and help from the community.

Where can I get help and ask questions? Is Stack Overflow a good platform for me?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: as long as you don't program that, no

Comment: Re *"want to support"*: Do you mean *"want support"*?

Answer (score 8):

No, you cannot ask questions about computer networking on Stack Overflow. That would be off-topic. This site is only for questions about programming.

We do not make recommendations of other sites for questions that we regard as off-topic. However, you can probably find some by searching the Internet.

Comment: there are programming questions around networking that are on topic

Comment: Yes, programming questions are on-topic, regardless of what they are about, as long as they are about programming.

Comment: @Gimby Not sure that I understand your objection to the Help Center's presentation. When I look at [the on-topic page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), I see very clearly in the first sentence that SO is for "professional and enthusiast programmers", and then *the very first bullet point* is "a specific programming problem". The [tour/about page](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)  seems equally clear about this, with the same language about "programmers" in the first sentence, and ending with "build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming".

Comment: @CodyGray what the heck. I guess I am beating a dead horse, it has been rewritten. Just goes to show, I complain about people not looking and then I don't look.